# Get random result from JPQL query over large table

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jpql

I'm currently using JPQL queries to retrieve information from a database. The purpose of the project is testing a sample environments through randomness with different elements so I need the queries to retrieve random single results all through the project.

I am facing that JPQL does not implement a proper function for random retrieval and postcalculation of random takes too long (14 seconds for the attached function to return a random result)

```
public Player getRandomActivePlayerWithTransactions(){

        List<Player> randomPlayers = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT pw.playerId FROM PlayerWallet pw JOIN pw.playerId p"
                + " JOIN p.gameAccountCollection ga JOIN ga.iDAccountStatus acs"
                + " WHERE (SELECT count(col.playerWalletTransactionId) FROM pw.playerWalletTransactionCollection col) > 0 AND acs.code = :status")
                .setParameter("status", "ACTIVATED")
                .getResultList();

        return randomPlayers.get(random.nextInt(randomPlayers.size()));
    }
```

As ORDER BY NEWID() is not allowed because of JPQL restrictions I have tested the following inline conditions, all of them returned with syntax error on compilation.

```
WHERE (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
WHERE Rnd % 100 < 10  
FROM TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)
```

Comment: JPQL allows "FUNCTION(...)" to use a native SQL function. But then the syntax of JPQL is defined in many places such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#bnf so why you just dump a load of SQL in and expect it to work I've no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. When retrieving the player I was also retrieving other unused related entity and all the entities related with that one and so one.

After adding `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` (don't fetch entity until required) to the problematic relation the performance of the query has increased dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider to generate a random number and skip to that result?
I mean something like this:

```
        String q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Player p";
        Query query=entityManager.createQuery(q);
        Number countResult=(Number) query.getSingleResult();
        int random = Math.random()*countResult.intValue();
        List<Player> randomPlayers = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT pw.playerId FROM PlayerWallet pw JOIN pw.playerId p"
            + " JOIN p.gameAccountCollection ga JOIN ga.iDAccountStatus acs"
            + " WHERE (SELECT count(col.playerWalletTransactionId) FROM pw.playerWalletTransactionCollection col) > 0 AND acs.code = :status")
            .setParameter("status", "ACTIVATED")
            .setFirstResult(random)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I have considered it but the result returned by the query is a subset of all the players, so the random counter can generate a result identifier out of the subset.

Comment: so use the same query for doing the count : "SELECT count(pw.playerId) ..." if its not too heavy ...

Comment: That's the thing its too heavy.